# Can I use an update stored procedure to save a view with breeze?

Tags: entity-framework-6, breeze

I have a view that has one field that is editable.

My thought was to create an update query and map it to that view, but breeze is throwing an error when I call SaveChanges.

** Error **

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at i._prepareSaveResult (breeze.min.js:formatted:5066)
at Object.it.AbstractDataServiceAdapter.i.saveChanges.n.ajax.success (breeze.min.js:formatted:4755)
at n (breeze.min.js:formatted:4818)
at angular.js:9408
at processQueue (angular.js:13248)
at angular.js:13264
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14282)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
at done (angular.js:9698)
```

**EDIT**

My view is mapped to an entity

```
public partial class Shop
{
    public Shop()
    {
        this.Notes = new HashSet<SoNote>();
    }

    public int SoId { get; set; }
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    //[other properties removed for brevity]
    public string ShopTech { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderEdit OrderEdit { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SoNote> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

}

SoId and DetailId are my key and I want the user to be able to update ShopTech.

This is using model first.

Comment: Is your view mapped to an entity?  What does it look like?

Comment: Yes, mapped to an entity, see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this error is the actual root cause. How is your view defined and what kind of database are you using? There are restriction on the database as far as updating a view is concerned. In most cases views are read-only and a SQL update statement against it will fail. Certain types of views are editable. For the other cases, EntityFramework 6 allows you to define insert/update/delete stored procedures. Have you defined an update stored procedure? As long as EF is able to update your entity, Breeze should be just fine with that.

Here's more info on using stored procs with code first. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx

Comment: I'm using SQL Server, my view is not updatable.    I defined an update stored procedure that updates just the table where the field is.  I don't have anything defined for insert or delete since those actions should never happen.

Comment: Does the call to SaveChanges reach the server or does it fail on the client before it reaches the server? If it reaches the server, is there an exception thrown on the server?

Comment: It fails on the client.

Comment: Ok, in that case there's something else going on. I noticed that you didn't specify the key properties in your class, given that you have a composite key. Have you done that using the fluent API? Also, can you switch to using breeze.debug.js to see where it actually fails. I'm interested in what is undefined. It's trying to read the property map of undefined. What is undefined?

Comment: hmmm...OK, I went to re-wire everything up

Comment: hmmm..., I went to re-wire everything up and switch to breeze.debug.js and now it's working.  Not sure what's different (I never got to the breeze.debug.js part) but I guess I don't really care.  I noticed I said I was using model first about, I meant database first.  In either case I not using the fluent API.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest versions of all the breeze scripts. breeze.debug.js is Breeze before minification. If minificaton causes an issue, that would be a problem.